# CakePHP : Saving Multiple Checkbox Associated Data

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I've been searching through other tutorials and guides but haven't found anything that is doing what I'm after.

I have a form that has a multiple select field that returns an array. This array (Locationattribute) I'm looking to insert into another model referencing the associated field and Location. 
This is where I run into problems. I get the array from my form as below but in all the examples that I've found I need to include both the field and location_id with each data entry as I don't know how many

```
Array
```

(

```
[Location] => Array
    (
        [name] => 
        [type] => 
        [specialities] => 
        [phone] => 
        [address_num] => 
        [address_street] => 
        [address_suffix] => 
        [address_state] => 
        [address_suburb] => 
        [address_postcode] => 
        [num_docs] => 
        [additional_services] => 
        [funds] => 
        [created_by] => 1
        [assigned_to] => 1
    )

[Hour] => Array
    (
        [mon_active] => 0
        [mon_open] => 10:00
        [mon_close] => 10:00
        [tues_active] => 0
        [tues_open] => 10:00
        [tues_close] => 10:00
        [wed_active] => 0
        [wed_open] => 10:00
        [wed_close] => 10:00
        [thurs_active] => 0
        [thurs_open] => 10:00
        [thurs_close] => 10:00
        [fri_active] => 0
        [fri_open] => 10:00
        [fri_close] => 10:00
        [sat_active] => 0
        [sat_open] => 10:00
        [sat_close] => 10:00
        [sun_active] => 0
        [sun_open] => 10:00
        [sun_close] => 10:00
    )

[Locationattibute] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [field] => patient_type
                [created_by] => 1
                [assigned_to] => 1
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Individuals
                        [1] => Families
                        [2] => Children
                        [3] => Elderly
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Is there any way to save this data in the format provided, if not how would I go about formatting my array to be acceptable format. I thought about just building it manually in my controller but I'm trying to adhere to best practices.

Note, I'm calling this save request from the Locations Model

For reference here are my relations

**Location**

```
class Location extends AppModel {

public $hasMany = array('Contact', 'Response', 'LocationAttribute');

public $hasOne = array('Hour');

public $belongsTo = array('User' => array(
    'className'     => 'User',
    'foreignKey'    => 'assigned_to',
    'dependent'     => false
));
```

**Locationattribute**

```
class Locationattribute extends AppModel {

public $belongsTo = array('Location' => array(
    'className'     => 'Location',
    'foreignKey'    => 'location_id',
    'dependent'     => false
));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Location model, you are using `LocationAttribute` in your `$hasMany` declaration, but in the model, and the data, you have `Locationattribute`. Are you sure this isn't the cause of your problems?

I'd be curious to see what the schema of the `Locationattribute` model's table looks like. Are you trying to save one row in it for each of the 4 data array elements, or do they each correspond to a field in the table?

Comment: thanks for spotting that typo. Changed it with no effect.

The goal was to insert a new record for each item selected, (ie, one record for each value in the data array, but each of the data records using the same field and location_id)

The schema is as follows
`locationattributes` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` varchar(250) ,
  `field` varchar(250) ,
  `location_id` int(11) ,
  `created_by` int(11) ,
  `assigned_to` int(11) ,
  `created` DATETIME ,
  `modified` DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)